# module 'skimage.filters' has no attribute 'gaussian_filter'

Tags: python, filter, gaussian, scikit-image

I'm trying to run [this example](https://gist.github.com/leonidk/8798fdbf38db120b8536d25ea2f8c3b4), but getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'skimage.filters' has no attribute 'gaussian_filter'
```

I checked the documentation, [here](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.gaussian_filter), and see that `filters` has `gaussian_filter`. What might be wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`gaussian_filter` has been removed in skimage 0.14.0 (see the release notes - http://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api_changes.html). You should now use `skimage.filters.gaussian` (http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.14.x/api/skimage.filters.html#skimage.filters.gaussian).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the mahotas module, which was because of the version. Un-installed and re-installed an older version resolved the problem